# Avoid reading value from XML column due to performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sqlperformance

I would like to improve the following SQL code. I have observed using SQL Server Profiler - XML reading operation is taking too much of time.

Here - `edata` is the XML column and the code shown is part of my main stored procedure, only below code is having an issue with performance. And `erequest` table is already indexed.

```
DECLARE @SFD TABLE 
( 
     etid    BIGINT, 
     eAmount DECIMAL(12, 2), 
     eDate   DATE
) 

INSERT INTO @SFD
    SELECT  
        tr.etid,
        tr.edata.value('(EData/Amount)[1]', 'DECIMAL(12, 2)') eAmount,
        tr.edata.value('(EData/DrawDate)[1]','date') eDate
    FROM    
        dbo.erequest tr
    WHERE  
        tr.accountid = @AccountId
```

In the above query, the following lines are taking too much time:

```
tr.edata.value('(EData/Amount)[1]', 'DECIMAL(12, 2)') eAmount,
tr.edata.value('(EData/DrawDate)[1]','date') eDate
```

Could someone kindly advise me how do I rewrite the above lines in the main SQL query so that I can see the performance improvement?

Kindly find the below query to populate the table data:

```
CREATE TABLE erequest
(
    etid BIGINT,
    edata XML,
    accountid INT
)

INSERT INTO erequest (etid, edata, accountid) 
VALUES (2145124897,
'<edata>
  <CardHolderName>ABCFDE</CardHolderName>
  <CardNumber>K6011</CardNumber>
  <Amount>555.17</Amount>
  <DrawDate>2022-05-18</DrawDate>
  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
</edata>',10)

INSERT INTO erequest (etid, edata, accountid) 
VALUES (2145124897,
'<edata>
  <CardHolderName>ABCFDE</CardHolderName>
  <CardNumber>K6011</CardNumber>
  <Amount>555.17</Amount>
  <DrawDate>2022-05-18</DrawDate>
  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
</edata>',20)

INSERT INTO erequest (etid, edata, accountid) 
VALUES (2145124897,
'<edata>
  <CardHolderName>ABCFDE</CardHolderName>
  <CardNumber>K6011</CardNumber>
  <Amount>555.17</Amount>
  <DrawDate>2022-05-18</DrawDate>
  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
</edata>',30)

INSERT INTO erequest (etid, edata, accountid) 
VALUES (2145124897,
'<edata>
  <CardHolderName>ABCFDE</CardHolderName>
  <CardNumber>K6011</CardNumber>
  <Amount>555.17</Amount>
  <DrawDate>2022-05-18</DrawDate>
  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
</edata>',12)

INSERT INTO erequest (etid, edata, accountid) 
VALUES (2145124897,
'<edata>
  <CardHolderName>ABCFDE</CardHolderName>
  <CardNumber>K6011</CardNumber>
  <Amount>555.17</Amount>
  <DrawDate>2022-05-18</DrawDate>
  <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
</edata>',16)

SELECT * FROM erequest
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rewrite the query, but instead you should consider using XML Indexes.

The description of XML Indexes can be found [here in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259). You will need a PRIMARY XML INDEX on the *edata* column and then I'd suggest a SECONDARY XML INDEX for PROPERTY which will help optimise the *value()* component of your query.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your response, actually edata column on table its already having PRIMARY XML INDEX .  All the necessary Indexes are already in place on this table - erequest

Comment: @Kumas What about _secondary_ XML indexes?

Comment: It is the Secondary XML index that will actually benefit you in this case

Comment: Could you please suggest me on which columns I need to apply the Secondary XML index on erequest  Table, basically this table has huge data and 10 columns in Production

Comment: You create the secondary index on the XML column. The syntax is "CREATE XML INDEX edataXMLProperty ON erequest (edata) USING XML INDEX nameOfMyPrimaryXMLIndex FOR PROPERTY;"

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, so basically I should create Primary and secondary XML index on the same XML column right ? in my case "edata" is the column name

Comment: That is correct